# Dialog Title Does not appear in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog. All of the items appear and it responds to touch, but the title doesn't appear. I checked other answers and they suggested setting "windowNoTitle" to "false" in the xml but this hasn't helped. Nor has trying "setTitle" after building the dialog (which is how it is written now). Why does my title not appear?

Here is the code for MainActivity:

```
package samapps.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogTest.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClick(int result){
        Log.d("tag","Executed on click");
    }

    //Called when the Send button is tapped
    public void sendMessage(View view){
       String[] text = {"Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"};
        String title = "Test Title";
        DialogFragment fragment = new DialogTest();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title_question",title);
        args.putStringArray("choices",text);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"testtest123");
        Log.d("tag","Executed after dialog");
}
```

}

And the dialog fragment:

```
package samapps.myfirstapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;



public class DialogTest extends DialogFragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public DialogTest() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onButtonClick(int result);
    }



    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Bundle theBundle = this.getArguments();

        String[] choices = theBundle.getStringArray("choices");
        String choiceTitle = theBundle.getString("choice_title");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getParent());
        }
        builder.setTitle(choiceTitle);

        builder.setItems(choices,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                mListener.onButtonClick(which);
            }
        });

        Dialog thisDialog = builder.create();
        thisDialog.setTitle(choiceTitle);
        return thisDialog;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

}
```

And for what it's worth, here's fragment_dialog_test.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="samapps.myfirstapp.DialogTest"
    android:windowNoTitle="false"
    style="@style/CustomDialog">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

with this in "Styles.xml"

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be because you are setting the title extra with key ""title_question" but then expecting it in the dialog to be set with key "choice_title"

try changing to

```
 public void sendMessage(View view){
       String[] text = {"Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"};
        String title = "Test Title";
        DialogFragment fragment = new DialogTest();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title_question",title);
        args.putStringArray("choices",text);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"testtest123");
        Log.d("tag","Executed after dialog");
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `DialogFragment`, you are using wrong `KEY` to get title `theBundle.getString("choice_title")`. Try using `title_question`.

**Use:**

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Bundle theBundle = this.getArguments();

    String[] choices = theBundle.getStringArray("choices");
    String choiceTitle = theBundle.getString("title_question");
    ...........
}
```